# RxJs - Can I use a BehaviorSubject to create a timer?

Tags: rxjs, behaviorsubject

I created a time loader that I can stop and restart using observable interval:

```
   start(time) {

    this.max = time;
    this.intervalObs = Observable.interval(time)
      .takeWhile(_ => !this.isFinished)
      .do(i =>{this.current += 1 ; console.log(this.current);} )
     this.intervalSub$ = this.intervalObs.subscribe();
  }

  finish() {
    this.intervalSub$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

and I want to do the exact same thing using behavior subjects. Is it possible and how ?

Comment: It is not clear why and where you need a BehaviorSubject. Please, update your question to add more details to the logic you're trying to implement and issues you're facing. Then we'll be of better help

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong. `Subject`s are both `Observer` and `Observable`. In your example, at least the way I understood it, you're using.. an interval, which means `.interval()` implementation is sufficient.

So the question is - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in my example when I try to unsubscribe in the finish() method , I get an error that I'm trying to unsubscribe from undefined , which means that the subscription I kept reference to is undefined there. so I wanted to do that in another way using behavior subject

Comment: @M.Maria, it's most likely that you're calling either `start` or `finish` on a different/empty context. See this [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to get more details on usage of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subjected called finalise you can complete the observable with that

```
finalise = new Subject();

this.intervalObs.pipe(takeUntil(this.finalise)).subscribe();

finish() {
  // When finalise emits the other observable completes
  this.finalise.next();
}
```